# Given a convex polytope, is the Chebyshev center unique?

Tags: geometry, optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, least-squares

Consider a convex polytope over n-dimensions defined by m linear inequalities.
Is the Chebyshev Center ([Chebyshev Center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_center)) unique?

Currently, I am getting different coordinates for the center in MATLAB and python - especially in high dimensions (>10).

Comment: Have you proven that the set is bounded?

Answer (score 0):

Since the polytope is a convex set and that the norm is a convex function, the global optimum should be unique. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_center#Mathematical_representation).

How are you computing it ?

Comment: I write it is a linear program and use linprog (MATLAB"s or python ) to solve it .   The matlab version is implemented here - https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34987-chebycenter-a-b-r0     This implementation is not wrong because I get the correct and SAME answers for low dimensions.  How is this possible?  I am happy to send you my python and MATLAB files if you want to take a look ?

Comment: As @Michael Grant suggested, maybe your sets are unbounded. The implementations look good.